# Ajax issue with Zscaler

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

On my page I have this ajax call:

```
$.getJSON(
    "@Url.Action("GetSchedulers")",
    { start: start, end: end },
    function(data) {
       fillCalendar(data);
    }
);
```

Everything works OK, except when I try to access it behind a Zscaler proxy, then the browser returns a CORS error:

```
"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."
```

The Request url is `https://gateway.zscaler.net/auD?origurl={my_url}`.

Does anyone know how to send the request without it being filtered by zscaler?

Comment: Does this work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28359412/495455 ? If it does then you need to reconfigure Zscaler or use a different proxy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to enable [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) in your ASP.NET website, and allow the `https://gateway.zscaler.net` domain.  CORS is required when a resource in a page (e.g. AJAX request) is to a different domain than what was used to serve the page.   According to [RFC 6454](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6454), the scheme  (http vs https), address, and port must match.

Assuming you have an ASP.NET web API project serving `GetSchedulers` requests, follow the [Asp.Net WebAPI instructions](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api):

1. Add the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors nuGet package
2. Add `config.EnableCors();` to the `void Register(HttpConfiguration config)` method
3. Add this attribute to your controller: `[EnableCors(origins: "https://gateway.zscaler.net", headers: "*", methods: "*")]`

If you're using a different server side implementation, then the instructions will be slightly different.  For example, if you're using OWIN, then use the [Microsoft.Owin.Cors](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Cors) nuGet package.

Comment: ZScaler appears to be a web security proxy. Is it common for people to need to add third party proxies to their website for ajax calls?

Comment: Yes, for availability.  If one server goes down, the proxy will route to the other.

Answer (score 1):

Try using JSON-P for the request: http://json-p.org/. If this doesn't work, look into configuring the backend resource to accept requests from a different domain.

Answer (score 0):

Only option is to disable Zscaler from your localhost. That can be done using ***regedit***. Zscaler is usually configured only for workstations. When you deploy your application to test/production server it should work there.

Regedit step-by-step instructions for disabling Zscaler below.

Disable the Automatic Proxy Result Cache by using the following registry key:
**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings**

Value: **EnableAutoproxyResultCache**

Type: **REG_DWORD**

Data value: **0** = disable caching

If the registry key is not present, you can create the registry key by using the following registry file:

**[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]"EnableAutoProxyResultCache"=dword:00000000"**